# Page rendering &amp; instead of &

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have some code in my wordpress installation. I wrote a function to display the post title in a place in my theme. I want to get the html as the post title redirect from my function.

I name the title `"A &amp; B"`. But I get the exact  `A &amp; B` in my theme instead of `A & B`. What am I doing wrong? Is there any php function for that ?

Comment: Note to people reading this post. SO is changing `&amp;` to &. He's getting `&amp;` in his titles vs &. He wants an ampersand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you well, you maybe need [htmlspecialchars($string)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) function.

Comment: Than this is what he want.

Comment: Right you are. Either way this wont work as Wordpress is probably calling `htmlentities()` on the title.

Comment: I used the strip_tags function for change the html symbol '&amp;' to '&'. But i cant find any change.

Answer (score 0):

Just use & in the post title.

Then depending on how you output use [WordPress validation and escaping](http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation) (perhaps [esc_html](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_html), or perhaps better, [the_title filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_title)  ).

If you're outputting using the_title(); you don't need to do anything, just let WordPress do the work.

Comment: So escape it on output - I provided the links that do that for you. See esc_html - http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation#Text_Nodes it says "Encodes < > & " ' (less than, greater than, ampersand, double quote, single quote). Very similar to esc_attr."

Answer (score 0):

Just use A & B instead.
Use & when defining a title.

Comment: Make a tour here [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)